# Device independent pixel in UWP-XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to fix the position of button to a particular point in uwp app. I have used margin to positioning it. But when running in another windows device it seems misplaced. How can I use DIP values in it? Is it possible to use dip instead of px for each control as in android?

```
 <Button x:Name="btnIcon" Height="200px" Width="300px" Click="btnIcon_Click"  Margin="0,578,280,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
```

Answer (score 0):

In the vast majority of cases (and your case), px values in XAML ARE device-independent units.

Also, most double length units will default to px so you don't usually have to specify the `px` suffix in markup.

Perhaps however, you need to consider using different logic to place your item. You're currently anchoring it to be 280 dip's from the right side of the screen and 578 from the top, is that what you're really intending on doing? Were you aiming to centre it or something?

Comment: yes ,want to display it 280 dip's from the right side of the screen and 578 from the top,